# window.location.href going a folder back?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a html document that is located at `localhost/r/index.php`, but when I do `window.location.href="localhost"` it sends me to `locahost/r/localhost` which I don't want. I want my script to send me to `localhost`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just `/` should work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use `/` to denote the root directory of your webserver:

```
window.location.href="/";
```

Or, you can use a full url:

```
window.location.href="http://localhost";
```

Answer (score 4):

`window.location.href="localhost"` =>
`window.location.href="/"`

Answer (score 2):

The path of the link is relative to the current page. You should use a path pointing to the root (i.e. `localhost`), so you should replace your code with `window.location.href="/"`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're already on `localhost`, then use `/` to go to the root, but in general, if you want to go to a particular domain, you need to include a scheme or `//`:

```
window.location.href = 'http://localhost';

// or

// uses the same scheme as whatever is currently displayed
window.location.href = '//localhost';
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `location` to a full url such as `http://localhost`

for instance:

```
window.location = "http://localhost";
```

You can verify this in the console.